# For loop with specific interval and bash calculator

Tags: bash, shell

I am quite new in bash scripting and therefore I have a very simple question.
I wrote a simple code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

    for i in 450 500 550 600 650 700 750 800 850 900 950 1000
        do
            mkdir $i'K'
            cd $i'K'
            sigma=$(echo "scale=5;(8.61734e-05*$i))" | bc)
            cp ../INCAR_default .
            sed 's/_s_/'$sigma'/g' INCAR_default > INCAR
            rm INCAR_default
        done
```

Now, I have two questions:
1. How can I modify the script for the 'for loop' so that I always maintain a specific interval? e.g, here the interval is 50. I know the script for a interval of '1' but not for a specific interval.

2. If I run this script then I am getting the following error:
   "(standard_in) 1: syntax error"

Can anybody come with both the solution of my queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a C-style for-loop

```
for (( i = 450; i <= 1000; i += 50 )); do
    ....
done
```

For the second part, that's an error message from `bc` telling you it doesn't like the input you're providing it. Looks like you have two `)`, but only one `(`.

> ```
> sigma=$(echo "scale=5;(8.61734e-05*$i))" | bc)
> ```

Comment: Hi geirha, thanks for comments. 1st problem is solved, but the second problem is still existing. It still says '(standard_in) 1: syntax error' even after removing the extra ')'.

Comment: @TanmoyChakraborty, looks like it doesn't support the e-syntax at all.

Comment: Anyway, it's working if I write '0.0000861734' instead of '8.61734E-05'. But I was wandering why the 'E-05' is not working.

Comment: @TanmoyChakraborty it just doesn't accept that syntax, I guess..?  you can use  `8.61734 * 10^-5` instead though